# I want to load specific data parameters I pulled from a weather api and load it into an sql database as the hours change

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json, web-scraping

Okay so I am pulling data from visual crossing weather api and I want to pull the date, hours, weather conditions, uv index, temperature, sunrise and sunset. I extracted the data using the json commands, but I am unable to get information for each hour. I have tried everything could someone please help me out. How could read temperature conditions for each hour for a specific location.

This is what I have so far:

```
import mysql.connector
import requests
import json
from urllib import parse
from datetime import datetime

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="qwww",
    database="weather_information"
)
BaseURL = 'https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/'

GeoUser = "xxx"

while True:
    try:
        Location = input("Enter the city name:") # user enters City name
        Base_GeoURL = 'http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON' #sets GeoNames URL
        Geo_params = {"q": f"{Location}"} #setting the provided city name as a parameter

        Geo_queryString = parse.urlencode(Geo_params)
        Geo_URL = Base_GeoURL + "?" + Geo_queryString + "&maxRows=5&username=" + GeoUser
        Geo_URL = Geo_URL.replace(" ", "")
        response = requests.get(Geo_URL, verify=True)  # Find a way to get this go through SSL
        Locateinfo = response.json()
        if(Locateinfo["totalResultsCount"] == 0):
            print("Invalid City, Please Re-enter city name")
        else:
            print("Valid City!")
            break
    except ConnectionError:
        print("Connection Error!!")
while True:
    try:
        SDate_String = input("Please enter start date in yyyy/mm/dd format")
        format = ' %Y/%m/%d'
        StartDate = datetime.strptime(SDate_String, format)
        break
    except ValueError:
            print("Invalid Date")
while True:
    try:
        EDate_String = input("Please enter end date in yyyy/mm/dd format")
        format = ' %Y/%m/%d'
        EndDate = datetime.strptime(EDate_String, format)
        print('Loading...')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Date")

diff_days = (EndDate - StartDate)
print(diff_days.days)

if ((StartDate.year == EndDate.year) and (StartDate.month == EndDate.month) and (StartDate.day == EndDate.day)):
    SStartDate = StartDate.strftime(" %Y/%m/%d")
    StartDate = SStartDate.split('/')
    Syear = StartDate[0]
    Smonth = StartDate[1]
    Sday = StartDate[2]

    SEndDate = EndDate.strftime(" %Y/%m/%d")
    EndDate = SEndDate.split('/')
    Eyear = EndDate[0]
    Emonth = EndDate[1]
    Eday = EndDate[2]

    print('Request for forecast data in progress...')
    params = {"unitGroup": "metric", "key": "wwww", "contentType": "json"}
    querystring = parse.urlencode(params)
    URL = BaseURL + Location + "/" + Syear + "-" + Smonth + "-" + Sday + "/" + Eyear + "-" + Emonth + "-" + Eday + "?" + querystring
    URL = URL.replace(" ", "")
    print(URL)


else:
    SStartDate = StartDate.strftime(" %Y/%m/%d")
    StartDate = SStartDate.split('/')
    Syear = StartDate[0]
    Smonth = StartDate[1]
    Sday = StartDate[2]

    SEndDate = EndDate.strftime(" %Y/%m/%d")
    EndDate = SEndDate.split('/')
    Eyear = EndDate[0]
    Emonth = EndDate[1]
    Eday = EndDate[2]

    print('Request for history data in progress...')

    params = {"unitGroup": "metric","key": "www", "contentType": "json"}
    querystring = parse.urlencode(params)
    URL = BaseURL + Location + "/" + Syear + "-" + Smonth + "-" + Sday + "/" + Eyear + "-" + Emonth + "-" + Eday + "?"+ querystring
    URL = URL.replace(" ", "")
    print(URL)

    response = requests.get(URL).json()
    weatherdata = json.loads(response.content)
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        passwd="qwww",
        database="weather_information"
    )
    cursor = db.cursor
    for item in weatherdata:
        date=item.get("resolveAddress")
        
        cursor.execute()


        # weatherdata = response.json()
        # weatherdata = json.loads(response.content)

        # print(weatherdata['resolvedAddress'])

        #for x in range(diff_days.days + 1):
           # date = weatherdata['days'][x]['datetime']
            #print(date)

        #    for i in range(24):
        #       print('HOUR:', weatherdata['days'][x]['hours'][i]['datetime'])
        #       print('TEMP:', weatherdata['days'][x]['hours'][i]['temp'])
        #        print('UVINDEX:', weatherdata['days'][x]['hours'][i]['uvindex'])
        #        print('WINDSPEED:', weatherdata['days'][x]['hours'][i]['windspeed'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no python dev so this is likely sub-optimal but at least it works. I have stripped out the MySQL bits as they are not yet implemented, nor are they key to

> read temperature conditions for each hour for a specific location

Your requirement for the space at the start of the date inputs makes no sense so I stripped that -

```
while True:
    try:
        SDate_String = input("Please enter start date in yyyy/mm/dd format: ")
        format = '%Y/%m/%d'
        StartDate = datetime.strptime(SDate_String, format)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Date")
```

The if...else conditional blocks serve no purpose as both branches do the same thing so I have removed them. If you need to add them back in, you can compare the two datetime objects directly instead of comparing their year, month & day attributes. The first two blocks of code in the conditional branches achieve nothing -

```
if ((StartDate.year == EndDate.year) and (StartDate.month == EndDate.month) and (StartDate.day == EndDate.day)):
    SStartDate = StartDate.strftime(" %Y/%m/%d")
    StartDate = SStartDate.split('/')
    Syear = StartDate[0]
    Smonth = StartDate[1]
    Sday = StartDate[2]

    SEndDate = EndDate.strftime(" %Y/%m/%d")
    EndDate = SEndDate.split('/')
    Eyear = EndDate[0]
    Emonth = EndDate[1]
    Eday = EndDate[2]

    print('Request for forecast data in progress...')
    params = {"unitGroup": "metric", "key": "wwww", "contentType": "json"}
    querystring = parse.urlencode(params)
    URL = BaseURL + Location + "/" + Syear + "-" + Smonth + "-" + Sday + "/" + Eyear + "-" + Emonth + "-" + Eday + "?" + querystring
    URL = URL.replace(" ", "")
    print(URL)


else:
    SStartDate = StartDate.strftime(" %Y/%m/%d")
    StartDate = SStartDate.split('/')
    Syear = StartDate[0]
    Smonth = StartDate[1]
    Sday = StartDate[2]

    SEndDate = EndDate.strftime(" %Y/%m/%d")
    EndDate = SEndDate.split('/')
    Eyear = EndDate[0]
    Emonth = EndDate[1]
    Eday = EndDate[2]

    print('Request for history data in progress...')

    params = {"unitGroup": "metric","key": "www", "contentType": "json"}
    querystring = parse.urlencode(params)
    URL = BaseURL + Location + "/" + Syear + "-" + Smonth + "-" + Sday + "/" + Eyear + "-" + Emonth + "-" + Eday + "?"+ querystring
    URL = URL.replace(" ", "")
    print(URL)
```

becomes -

```
print('Request for forecast data in progress...')
params = {'unitGroup': 'uk', 'key': 'wwww', 'contentType': 'json'}
querystring = parse.urlencode(params)
URL = BaseURL + parse.quote(Location) + "/" + StartDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "/" + EndDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "?" + querystring
print(URL)
```

The next block of code, which sends the request to the API, is still inside your `else:` block but presumably should be outside.

```
# could be
response = requests.get(URL)
weatherdata = response.json()

# or
response = requests.get(URL)
weatherdata = json.loads(response.text)

# but not half and half
response = requests.get(URL).json()
weatherdata = json.loads(response.content)
```

Piecing it back together you end up with something like this -

```
import requests
import json
from urllib import parse
from datetime import datetime

BaseURL = 'https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/'

GeoUser = "xxx"

while True:
    try:
        Location = input("Enter the city name: ") # user enters City name
        # put your api.geonames.org code back in here
        break
    except ConnectionError:
        print("Connection Error!!")
while True:
    try:
        SDate_String = input("Please enter start date in yyyy/mm/dd format: ")
        format = '%Y/%m/%d'
        StartDate = datetime.strptime(SDate_String, format)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Date")
while True:
    try:
        EDate_String = input("Please enter end date in yyyy/mm/dd format: ")
        format = '%Y/%m/%d'
        EndDate = datetime.strptime(EDate_String, format)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Date")

diff_days = (EndDate - StartDate)
print('DiffDays: ', diff_days.days)

print('Request for forecast data in progress...')
params = {'unitGroup': 'uk', 'key': 'wwww', 'contentType': 'json'}
querystring = parse.urlencode(params)
URL = BaseURL + parse.quote(Location) + "/" + StartDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "/" + EndDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "?" + querystring
print(URL)

response = requests.get(URL)
weatherdata = response.json()

print('Resolved address: ' + weatherdata['resolvedAddress'])

for day in weatherdata['days']:
    print('Date: ', day['datetime'])

    for hour in day['hours']:
        print('HOUR: ', hour['datetime'])
        print('TEMP: ', hour['temp'])
        print('UVINDEX: ', hour['uvindex'])
        print('WINDSPEED: ', hour['windspeed'])
```